# Spring MVC with HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I use Spring MVC (no Spring Boot) with HATEOAS in order to get HAL-FORMS with Affordance response like this:

```
      "_links": {
        "index": {
          "href": "/api"
           ...
        }
```

But i still get the JSON format:

```
      "links": [
            {
              "href": "/api"   
            }
           ...
          ]
```

In my code I already use:

```
    @RestController
    @EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL_FORMS)
    public class myController {...}
```

```
        @GetMapping(value = "/api", produces = { "application/prs.hal-forms+json" })
        ResponseEntity<EntityModel<E>> get(Object object) {...}
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
      <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
            <beans:property name="messageConverters">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
        
        <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
        <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        </beans:bean>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a corresponding MessageConverter set in place?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question above so you can see.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that the JackSON Converter is not able to convert to HAL-Forms. Maybe you need some extra conversion routine?